# how to pass perameter to function?

Tags: javascript, function

i have a button on marker and this button call a function `onclick="mapcheck(us_ids)"` but on click button console saya us_ids is not defined here is my code

```
var us_ids = [1 , 2 , 3];  
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i , us_ids) {
        return function() {
            
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]  +'<button onclick="mapcheck(us_ids)">Click me</button>');
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
```

Comment: You've declared `us_ids` as a parameter but it seems you just want to get the variable that's declared outside the function. Just remove the parameter and it would work. Otherwise, you need to pass it like you pass `marker` and `i`. Speaking of which, you probably don't need to pass those, either. You likely don't need the whole outer function shown here.

Comment: There is no php in this code, please keep your tags relevant.  Also, no idea because you haven't show where `us_id[1]` comes from

Comment: no i want to pass pera meter in onclick="mapcheck(us_ids)" so u mean i should pass it in  (marker, i , us_ids));?